# Assign a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create an array that generates random values, then assign a pointer to that array in order to use it in other functions.

Question 1: Is this the right approach?

Question 2: When I run the code below, my pointer function generates values inconsistent with what the actual array's value is. What am I doing wrong?

```
int size = 100;
int theray[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    theray[i] = (rand()%100);
}
//Output array
cout<<"The array: ";
for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
{
    cout<<theray[j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;

int (*parray)[100] = &theray;
cout<<"The array pointer: ";
for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
{
    cout<<*parray[k]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: What to you mean by "then assign a pointer to that array in order to use it in other functions"? This smells bad

Comment: Pointers are [**EVIL**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html)!

Comment: `int theray[size];` this isn't valid C++; `size` needs to be declared `const` for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: is this the right approach?

No. The right approach is to use `std::vector<int>` if `size` is not known at compile time<sup>1</sup>, and `std::array<int, size>` if it is<sup>2</sup>. There is no need for pointers here.

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  // do stuff with v
}

...

std::vector<int> v(size); // vector with size elements
// do something with v

// pass v to a function
foo(v);
```

> Question 2: when I run the code below, my pointer function generates values inconsistent with what the actual array's value is. What am I doing wrong?

If you use C++ idioms you won't even encounter this problem, so I consider the question moot. However, in your case you have a problem of operator precedence: be explicit about applying de-reference `*` before access `[]`:

```
cout<< (*parray)[k] << " ";
```

<sup>1</sup> As shown in the example, you can use an `std::vector` as a fixed size array, where the size need not be known at runtime. Just bear in mind that it is possible to change it's size after construction.

<sup>2</sup>In your example, `size` is not a compile time constant so you cannot use `std::array`. However, if you had declared it as `const int size = 100;` then it would be considered a compile time constant.

Comment: @Dukeling: The answer states "compile time" because it *means* "compile time". The only way to have variable length array in C++ is `std::vector`.

Comment: @JanHudec I may have been a bit unfamiliar with how `std::array` works, but after a quick Google search I see now.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit off in three ways. First, there is no need to use *&theray*. Array names already reference a memory address. You can simply assign the pointer to *theray*. Second, you're declaring an array of 100 pointers. Based on your description, it sounds like you just want one pointer that points to the array. Your declaration should just be int *parray instead of int *parray [100]. Finally, once you have a pointer to the array, you can access elements of the array the same way you would with the original array, only with the name of the pointer, instead of the name of the array. Try changing your last block of code (starting with the pointer declaration to this:

```
int *parray;
parray = theray;
cout<<"The array pointer: ";
for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
{
    cout<<parray[k]<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Question 1

> Is this the right approach?

Usually not. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For high level semantics you'd in most cases use `std::vector<int>` or, if the size is fixed and you are using C++11, `std::array<int, size>`. If you actually have to go down to the pointer level, you'd usually write it like this:

```
int *parray = theray;
cout<<"The array pointer: ";
for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
{
    cout<<parray[k]<<" ";
}
```

This works because arrays will degrade to pointers, and the `[…]` subscripts work on these pointers just like they work on the original arrays.

## Question 2

> When I run the code below, my pointer function generates values inconsistent with what the actual array's value is, what am I doing wrong?

`*parray[k]` gets interpreted as `*(parray[k])` while you intend to use it as `(*parray)[k]`.

Comment: btw, `int size=100; int theray[size];` can't pass in some compilers. should use `const`.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: is this the right approach?

**No**. Use `std::vector<>` for arrays whose size can change dynamically (at run-time). Prefer avoiding pointers and manual memory management.

> Question 2: when I run the code below, my pointer function generates values inconsistent with what the actual array's value is. What am I doing wrong?

First of all, the fact of creating pointers so you can pass the array to a function. This is not necessary. Here is how I would use classes from  the C++ Standard Library to write that program (in C++11):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// Sample function that prints the vectors's content
void foo(std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}

int main()
{
    // Populate the vector...
    size_t sz = 10;
    std::vector<int> v(sz);
    generate(begin(v), end(v), [] () { return rand() % 100; });

    // Pass it to a function...
    foo(v);
}
```